# Production migration fresh

Tags: php, database-migration, laravel-5.6

How does it work if I want to add a new column in my production table? I know that I will loose all the data when I make a migration:fresh.

1) is it possible to change the migration and add a new column as I did with the fastnetnr column?

```html
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kontaktforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('navn');
            $table->string('mobilnr');
            //new fastnetnr column added
            $table->string('fastnetnr')->nullable();
            $table->string('mail');
            $table->string('emne');
            $table->text('beskrivelse');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

2) Or do I have to add a new column with php artisan so the output is like this?

```html
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('kontaktforms', function($table) {
        $table->string('fastnetnr')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically you can do it by following steps;

1. rollback your table `php artisan migrate:rollback` or `php artisan
   migrate:rollback --step=1`
2. edit your migration file
3. migration back `php artisan migrate`

but it's not a best practice, especially in production. so you have to create new migration file for modify table and migrate it.

**create new migration file**

```
php artisan make:migration add_fastnetnr_to_kontaktforms_table --table=kontaktforms
```

**and add new column like this**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('kontaktforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('fastnetnr')->nullable();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::table('kontaktforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('fastnetnr');
    });
}
```

**and migrate**

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: What if I do not make a migrate:rollback, but only migrate:fresh? Would it damage the production tables?

Comment: migrate:fresh command will drop all tables and re-run all migrations